# Maven GWT - Output only Javascript files

Tags: java, javascript, maven, gwt

I'm trying to generate Javascript from Java files using GWT.
I'm using Maven to build my GWT project but now I'm trying to shorten the Maven build times.
I'm no Maven expert and so I've come here..
It seems Maven is generating .class files from my Java files which I don't think is necessary because I just need the Javascript files and GWT is a source to source compiler.
I don't need any jars, wars or anything else. Just Javascript files.
Here is my POM file:

```
<project 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.app</groupId>
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.timepedia.exporter</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtexporter</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <webappDirectory>
                            ${WEBAPP_DIRECTORY} 
                        </webappDirectory> 
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's ok that maven compiles your .java files and produces .class using javac, that guarantees that your java syntax is correct and that you can use your sources in any IDE. So ignore them.
2. In order to compile your code to JS, you have to configure maven to execute the GWT compiler, it's done using the [gwt-maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/). Note that your java code should be compatible with the [emulated GWT JRE](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html), so there are some constrains to consider.
3. Once you have everything working, you will get your JS code in the folder `target/artifactId-version/moduleName`. You will get all the stuff you need to publish in your webserver. So you will get one `module.nocache.js` file which is the bootstrap script to load your code, and some `MD5.cache.js` or `MD5.cache.html` files depending on what linker you use in your project and the number of permutations you select.
4. Of course you could [collapse all permutations](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations) and produce an unique output file if you use the [single script linker](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.6.0-rc4/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/core/linker/SingleScriptLinker.java).

Based on your configuration, it seems you want to export your java api to js using [gwt-exporter](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/), you can use [jsUpload](https://github.com/manolo/gwtupload/blob/master/jsupload/pom.xml) maven project as reference which is the JS exported version of the [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) library written in GWT.

[EDIT]

For a web service producing JS, I will call the compiler directly instead of doing through maven. It will save a lot of the time mvn spends parsing config, checking dependencies, running unneeded tasks, etc. You can simply run maven compile and grab the output of the `ps -feawww` or take a look to gwt-maven [CompileMojo](https://github.com/gwt-maven-plugin/gwt-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt/shell/CompileMojo.java) to figure out how to compose the args list. I will consider using draft-mode compilation with incremental option.

Comment: 1. What I'm trying to build is a web service that takes Java code and transforms it to Javascript, so it's actually really important to me that the build will be fast as I'm executing Maven on my server.
2. The gwt-maven-plugin is already working in the POM I provided. Javascript files are generated and everything is working fine. The only thing I'm trying to improve is the build times.
jsUpload looks very interesting.

Comment: Skipping java->class will save you far less than 1% of your build time - the java->js is the expensive part (though getting faster all the time). A better idea might be to look at avoiding optimizations (and so bigger JS), to the point of emitting Super Dev Mode code (which can recompile in a second or two for small changes).

Comment: consider using draft mode and incremental option, and call directly the compiler from your service instead of fork to mvn, edited my response.

Comment: I did as you suggested and called the compiler directly. I called Maven with the -X option and in Maven's logs I was able to spot the call it makes to the GWT compiler. Now I'm able to execute that call without invoking Maven which saves me about 5 seconds. Thanks a lot =)